# Mapbasic v15 open wor within existing mapview

Tags: mapbasic

Using `Run Application "G:\System\SSA\wor\Current\Townplanning_2018_v1\Zoning.wor"` that's called from within a mapbasic program I want to load the workspace in the current map view rather than in a new one.

If I have

```
Dim nWindowID As Integer
nWindowID = FrontWindow()
```

How can I tell the run application to open in this window? This has to be in v15 32bit and not 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

First capture the number of open window before opening the workspace:

```
nNumWindows = NumWindows()
```

Get the ID of the Map window to add the layers to:

```
nMID = FrontWindow()
```

Open the workspace and let it open the windows

```
Run Application "G:\System\SSA\wor\Current\Townplanning_2018_v1\Zoning.wor"
```

Find the map window. I just assume it's the last window opened by the workspace

```
nMIDNew = WindowID(NumWindows())
```

Now get the close string of the new map window and run it into the existing map

```
Set Window nMID Front
Run Command MapperInfo(nMIDNew, MAPPER_INFO_MERGE_MAP)
```

And finally, close the windows opened by the workspace

```
For nWID = NumWindows() to (nNumWindows + 1) Step -1
   Close Window WindowID(nWID)
Next
```

I haven't declared any of the variables I have used

Answer (score 1):

A workspace file is basically a list of mapbasic commands. One of them is usually "map from....", which creates a new mapper. If you want it to add to an existing mapper, try to replace it with "add map frontwindow()...". See the help file.